# drupal 7 programatically close comments in custom node type

Tags: nodes

I have created a content type programmatically. Also looked at http://drupal.org/node/1169864 but comments are not being close. Although I solve it by `variable_set('comment_mynodetype', '1')`. Any other help.
My code is below:

```
$t = get_t();

  $node = array(
    'type' => NODE_NAME,
    'name' => $t('My Node Type'),
    'base' => 'node_content',
    'locked' => TRUE,
    'node-preview' => 0,
    'node-options' => array('status'),
    'comment' => array('status' => 1),
    'description' => $t('A content type.'),
    'title_label' => $t('Title'),
    'custom' => FALSE
  );
  $content_type = node_type_set_defaults($node);
  //add body field using drupal function
  node_add_body_field($content_type, $t('Description'));
  node_type_save($content_type);
```

Any help ..

[UPDATED]

```
 $node = array(
        'type' => NODE_NAME,
        'name' => $t('My Node Type'),
        'base' => 'node_content',
        'locked' => TRUE,
        'node-preview' => 0,
        'node-options' => array('status'),
        'description' => $t('A content type.'),
        'title_label' => $t('Title'),
        'custom' => FALSE
      );
   //close comments
   variable_set('comment_mediasite', '1');
```

Answer (score 6):

`$node->comment` should be an integer (not an array). Acceptable values are:

- [`COMMENT_NODE_CLOSED`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21comment%21comment.module/constant/COMMENT_NODE_CLOSED/7)
- [`COMMENT_NODE_HIDDEN`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21comment%21comment.module/constant/COMMENT_NODE_HIDDEN/7)
- [`COMMENT_NODE_OPEN`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21comment%21comment.module/constant/COMMENT_NODE_OPEN/7)

Comment: so how to use it in $node object (in my code sample above) ?

Comment: I would try `'comment' => COMMENT_NODE_XXX` and test from there

Comment: I used 'comment' => COMMENT_NODE_CLOSED, but it is still comments opened.

Comment: I think 'comment' => COMMENT_NODE_CLOSED will work for a particular node, while i am going to close comments for all node of a particular NODE_TYPE. Help

Comment: @navneet Indeed, I was confused as your variable is called `$node`, not `$node_type` :) You'll have to use the `variable_set` method - until the node type is saved through the settings form, those variables don't actually exist, the comment module just uses defaults

Comment: @Clive.. Really sorry for that. Yes, variable_set() works but I was looking for any property to be set (at the time of content type creation) for closing comments. Thanks

Comment: That was my point - you can't :) There's no mechanism available to do it, even Drupal core uses only `variable_set` to set that data

Comment: Thanks for giving valuable point about drupal's mechanism. I was searching from many hours, you saved me.